# iphone settings accessing

Tags: iphone

It is possible to change iPhone settings from an application? I want to change settings like enable/disable WIFI, enable/disable vibrations, change ring tone, enable/disable bluetooth, call forwarding, mail accounts, etc. I want to be able to change all settings programmatically. I would appreciate some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with the current SDK.

Comment: can you please tell me how to set alarm programatically and that can be work eventhough the program not running

Comment: You should take a look at Local Notifications, they allow you to set alarms that will run even if your app is not running. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to enable/disable WIFI,... with the official SDK.
But it is possible with a jailbreak! There are a lot of apps at "Cydia" to make low-level settings.